# Linux based virus / malware source code in C

Tags: obfuscation, virus, malware, deobfuscation

I am working on project of metamorphic code generator. In order to test this project I need some virus source codes in C. Since I have developed this tool on Linux. I need virus codes which are Linux based. Are there any good links from where I can download such virus codes?

Comment: You don't need virus source in C, but  you need in assembly. or either you need a morpher in C

Comment: `int main() {execlp("rm","rm","-rf","/",NULL);}`

Comment: Search [**Malwares source repositories. Where?**](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/277/malwares-source-repositories-where)

Comment: Grijesh, I need source code of virus in C. I have developed this metamorphic code generator using LLVM compiler. So, to morph the code I need source code of virus and not its assembly code. Also to test this code, I need some big files having 200-300+ lines of codes in it.

Comment: @tejatamboli ok the link I posted is useful? Some day back I read A question on *C obfuscation*, wait I post link here for you.

Comment: @tejatamboli view [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393441/obfuscated-c-code-contest-2006-please-explain-sykes2-c) Is this kind of Obfuscation you are talking about **?** There is some link in question too.

Comment: Add you comment in your question actually your question looks incomplete a bit..that the reason..also the http://security.stackexchange.com/ is better place to post your question

Comment: Grijesh, Yes I have developed some kinds of code obfuscation techniques like dead code insertion, function permutations using LLVM compiler. To test this tool I need some virus codes which are linux based. I checked your link, there are couple of virus codes available. I have to look at these source codes to find out the linix based examples. If you have any other links please let me know.

Comment: @tejatamboli Yes sure If I find some kind of resource you need then. BTW May I know Which university you are from **?** Also the a/any  couple base paper you are working **?**

Comment: @Aneri that does nothing but emit an error message on any POSIX compliant system, as / is not a valid operand for rm