# Why does -~x equal x+1?

Tags: c, twos-complement

In [Obfuscated C Code Contest 2006. Please explain sykes2.c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15393441/2172038),

there is a statement "`-~i == i+1` because of twos-complement".

Can someone explain why this is the case?

Comment: Did you read e.g. [the Wikipedia article on two's-complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%27s_complement)?

Comment: Sorry, i was trying to answer the question. I tried to add an answer to the other question but they said it was not an answer.

Answer (score 4):

`-~x` is equal to `x+1` because `~x` is equivalent to `(0xffffffff-x)`. This is equal to `(-1-x)` in 2s complement, so `-~x` is `-(-1-x) = x+1`.