# What is the underscore actually doing in this Java code?

Tags: java, syntax

I just began to learn Java.

My friend who is helping me study just sent me this and said 'figure this out'.

Unfortunately I am unable to read this. It looks like Perl to me.

```
class _{_ _;_(){_=this;}}
```

What does it mean?

Comment: This question is being discussed [on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173714/can-we-nuke-this-too-localized-question). Let's take arguments for or against closing/deleting it there.

Comment: @anotherordinary You should probably ditch your friend as a programming teacher if he/she thought telling you to figure this out would be a good way to learn this language. Remembering irreverent trivia isn't useful at all. Much less when you are starting to learn a language.

Comment: @EnnoShioji Great point. "Irrelevant". Sorry.

Comment: is someone trying to create the "IOJCC" ? (google "IOCCC")

Comment: @EnnoShioji How is this "irrelevant trivia" that needs remembering? Anyone that calls himself a Java programmer should be able to understand this easily.

Comment: @phant0m: The "trivia" here I think is the fact that Java allows a single underscore as an identifier, which I don't think is useful knowledge.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

`_` is the class name. It's a very confusing one, but it works!

With the class renamed:

```
class Something {Something something;Something(){something=this;}}
```

And cleaned up:

```
class Something {
    Something something;
    Something() {
        something=this;
    }
}
```

And you can go crazy with this odd naming `:)`

```
class _{_ __;_ ____;_(){__=this;____=__;}_(_ ___){__=___;}}
```

In fact, Unicode is even supported, so this is valid:

```
class 合法類別名稱{合法類別名稱(){}}
```

Comment: I personally love the @Alvin's edit :)

Comment: There are few mistakes in your `get crazy` example. (1) you forgot to add semicolon after `____=__` (two times), (2) if you are trying to overload `_` method then you need to also pass type so `_(___)` should be `_(_ ___)`. Here is how it can look `class _{_ __;_ ____;_(){__=this;____=__;}_(_ ___){__ = ___;}}`. Wait a minute. Did I just debugged  underscores? It is time for a brake.

Comment: @Pshemo Lol, I never really meant to be serious about that code :P fixed

Comment: Get a +1 for the comment on my answer. Could not think of another way of rewarding you.

Answer (score 71):

`_` is the class name, underscore is a valid Java variable name, you just need to indent your code to deobfuscate it:

```
class _{
    _ _;
    _(){
     _=this;
   }
}
```

Like:

```
class A{
    A A;
    A(){
     A=this;
   }
}
```

**Edit:** thanks to  @Daniel Fischer

> Type names and variable names have different namespaces. and for example code `class FOO { FOO FOO; }` is valid in Java.

**Summary**

- `_` is a class name e.g at `class _{`
- `_` is a class member name e.g at `_ _;` and `_=this`
- `_` is a constructor name e.g. at `_()`

Remember: Java uses [**six different namespaces:**](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/cit591-2011/Pages/o-o-concepts.html)

> - Package names,
> - type names,
> - field (variable) names,
> - method names,
> - local variable names (including parameters), and
> - labels.
>
> In addition, each declared enum has its own namespace. Identical names of different types do not conflict; for example, *a method may be named the same as a local variable*.

Comment: There is no mistake. It compiles just fine as I typed. I just didn't understand it till now.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan type names and variable names have different namespaces. `class FOO { FOO FOO; }` works.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks..This is in Java only **?** ..any other language do this?

Comment: In Haskell, for example, types and values also have different namespaces. A difference there is that case has meaning, a type name must begin with an upper case letter, so you can't name any old value like a type, but only constructors, but `data Foo = Foo | Bar Int` works. It can only work, of course, in languages where you can figure out the category of an identifier from where it appears.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks a lot Deniel Fischer... I found it very interesting.

Comment: @anotherordinary read my updated answer I added a link also

Comment: @DanielFischer I have a cross question: In c++ also contractors and class name, function name is overloading and overriding  are same. Its dues to namespace or c++ compiler internally represent every function with different name **?** Sorry for bothering you again.

Comment: Uh, C++ isn't really my domain. But unless things changed since I last looked, overloading is resolved via name-mangling, with parameter types included in the "real" name in some way. I think type names and function/constructor names are in the same namespace in C++, but I'm not sure, and too lazy to look it up now.

Comment: Aren't field names and local variables in the same namespace? Otherwise you wouldn't be able to shadow the variables, as is commonly done in setter methods: `void setValue(String value) { this.value = value;}`

Comment: @JörnHorstmann No I mean yes both are in same *namespace*.

Comment: @anotherordinary Hi Did you read this question and its answer [Obfuscated C Code Contest 2006.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393441/obfuscated-c-code-contest-2006-please-explain-sykes2-c/15395030#15395030)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: In the comment you wrote that they're in the same namespace, but this contradicts your answer listing 6 different namespaces. I'd say "field vs local variable vs enum member" is all just scoping.

Comment: @maaartinus Yes I notice. But I think because we use `this` so both are in same name space. I didn't understand what do you mean by `'this is just scoping'` ..please add some info/link I am myself confused.

Answer (score 12):

well that’s good example . Java allows unicode to be identifiers so you can write something like:

```
class ⲥlass {
ⲥlass claѕѕ;
}
```

here class name's c is 'ⲥ' (U+2CA5 COPTIC SMALL LETTER SIMA) and

object name's 'ѕ' (U+0455 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER DZE).

Comment: You can't have a variable named `class`, it's a keyword.

Comment: @nickb : it is not Java keyword `'class'`. as I have mentioned that object name `'claѕѕ'` has `'ss'` which are non ascii characters. so actually object's name is `claѕѕ` is `cla\u0455\u0455'` I think this clears misunderstanding. :)