# What is the default type for C const?

Tags: c, types

I was writing some C code, and noticed what I thought to be an error, but was not. I had the following type declaration statement.

```
const fee;
```

However, it was uncaught initially because the compiler and I didn't catch it. So I was curious as to why C allows this and what is the default type.

Comment: Related to [What does it mean to declare a variable with a storage class specifier but no type specifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21359239/what-does-it-mean-to-declare-a-variable-with-a-storage-class-specifier-but-no-ty)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Only the original version of C language standard (ANSI/ISO C89/90) allows this. Such variable declaration defaults to type `int` in accordance with "implicit `int`" rule. That rule was present in C since the beginning of time. That's just how the language was originally defined.

Note that the *declaration-specifiers* portion of a declaration cannot be omitted completely, e.g. a mere

```
fee;
```

does not declare an `int` variable. It is illegal even in the original C. But once you add some sort of declaration specifier or qualifier, the declaration becomes legal and defaults to `int` type, as in

```
static fee;
const fee;
register fee;
```

However, all this is illegal in C99 and in later versions of language, since these versions of language specification outlawed "implicit int".

Comment: And to answer the question in the title, there is no default type for `const` declarations.

Comment: @AndreyT Thanks for the great clarification. I guess my gcc compiler is running on c90 mode. I will need to changed that.

Comment: [GCC defaults to `-std=gnu90`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html) while [clang builds C code according to the C99 standard](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#c) by default.