# Finding SHRT_MAX on systems without <limits.h> or <values.h>

Tags: c++

I am reading *The C++ Answer Book* by Tony L Hansen. It says somewhere that the value of SHRT_MAX (the largest value of a short) can be derived as follows:

```
const CHAR_BIT=           8;
#define BITS(type)       (CHAR_BIT*(int)sizeof(type))
#define HIBIT(type)      ((type)(1<< (BITS(type)-1)))
#define TYPE_MAX(type)   ((type)~HIBIT(type));
const SHRT_MAX=          TYPE_MAX(short);
```

Could someone explain in simple words what is happening in the above 5 lines?

Comment: Not an answer but an easier way to the result: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits   Line (2) is multiplication.

Comment: “How is CHAR_BIT used as a pointer type?”   There is this thing called [multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication).

Comment: @HenriMenke Okay

Comment: Note also that `CHAR_BIT` is already defined: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits

Comment: @RichardCritten Only if `<climits>` is available, but if `<limits.h>` isn't available, I don't expect `<climits>` to be. If it *is* available (as it is required to be on all conforming C++ implementations), there's no need to calculate anything at all, `SHRT_MAX` can just be used directly.

Comment: Note also that _"Note: this allows the extreme case in which bytes are sized 64 bits, all types (including char) are 64 bits wide, and sizeof returns 1 for every type."_ so `CHAR_BIT` does not have to be 8.

Comment: There is no standard C++ on systems without limits.h, so it isn't even clear what SHRT_MAX might mean.

Comment: @n.m. I think freestanding implementations are required to provide `<climits>` but are not required to provide `<limits.h>`, even though there is no good reason to provide the former without the latter. I don't expect such implementations to exist though.

Comment: Google says that this book is published in **1990**. I'd suggest stop reading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> const CHAR_BIT=           8;
> ```

Assuming `int` is added here (and below): `CHAR_BIT` is the number of bits in a `char`. Its value is assumed here without checking.

> ```
> #define BITS(type)       (CHAR_BIT*(int)sizeof(type))
> ```

`BITS(type)` is the number of bits in `type`. If `sizeof(short) == 2`, then `BITS(short)` is `8*2`.

Note that C++ does not guarantee that all bits in integer types other than `char` contribute to the value, but the below will assume that nonetheless.

> ```
> #define HIBIT(type)      ((type)(1<< (BITS(type)-1)))
> ```

If `BITS(short) == 16`, then `HIBIT(short)` is `((short)(1<<15))`. This is implementation-dependent, but assumed to have the sign bit set, and all value bits zero.

> ```
> #define TYPE_MAX(type)   ((type)~HIBIT(type));
> ```

If `HIBIT(short)` is `(short)32768`, then `TYPE_MAX(short)` is `(short)~(short)32768`. This is assumed to have the sign bit cleared, and all value bits set.

> ```
> const SHRT_MAX=          TYPE_MAX(short);
> ```

If all assumptions are met, if this indeed has all value bits set, but not the sign bit, then this is the highest value representable in `short`.

---

It's possible to get the maximum value more reliably in modern C++ when you know that:

- the maximum value for an unsigned type is trivially obtainable
- the maximum value for a signed type is assuredly either equal to the maximum value of the corresponding unsigned type, or that value right-shifted until it's in the signed type's range
- a conversion of an out-of-range value to a signed type does not have undefined behaviour, but instead gives an implementation-defined value in the signed type's range:

```
template <typename S, typename U>
constexpr S get_max_value(U u) {
    S s = u;
    while (s < 0 || s != u)
        s = u >>= 1;
    return u;
}

constexpr unsigned short USHRT_MAX = -1;
constexpr short SHRT_MAX = get_max_value<short>(USHRT_MAX);
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking it one line at a time:

```
const CHAR_BIT=           8;
```

Declare and initialize `CHAR_BIT` as a variable of type `const int` with
value `8`. This works because `int` is the default type (wrong: see comments below), though it’s
better practice to specify the type.

```
#define BITS(type)       (CHAR_BIT* (int)sizeof(type))
```

Preprocessor macro, converting a type to the number of bits in that
type. (The asterisk isn’t making anything a pointer, it’s for
multiplication. Would be clearer if the author had put a space before
it.)

```
#define HIBIT(type)      ((type)(1<< (BITS(type)-1)))
```

Macro, converting a type to a number of that type with the highest bit
set to one and all other bits zero.

```
#define TYPE_MAX(type)   ((type)~HIBIT(type));
```

Macro, inverting `HIBIT` so the highest bit is zero and all others are
one. This will be the maximum value of `type` if it’s a signed type and
the machine uses [two’s complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). The semicolon shouldn’t be there, but
it will work in this code.

```
const SHRT_MAX=          TYPE_MAX(short);
```

Uses the above macros to compute the maximum value of a `short`.

Comment: Note that in C++ there is no default type. Only C89/C90 allows it (and not C99 nor C11), and even then some consider it bad practice, as you say. Details at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171602/what-is-the-default-type-for-c-const

Comment: Ah, didn’t realize C++ had dumped the default type. I daresay many compilers still use it, though, and won’t even warn unless you tell them to.

Comment: At least none of the big 4 (gcc, icc, clang, msvc) allow it.

Comment: @Acorn MSVC optionally allows it. It issues an error by default, but allows that error to be turned into a warning or suppressed entirely.

Comment: Ah, the book was published in 1989. Things were probably a lot less strict back then. I do know that C++ has changed quite a bit since then.

Comment: @hvd: I am curious, how do you make it accept it (in C++ mode, i.e. not `/Tc`)?

Comment: @Acorn The same way you can suppress other diagnostics, for example using `/wd4430`.

Comment: @hvd: Oh, you literally meant disabling the error (!), rather than an option to somehow accept the code as valid. It works indeed, but it is odd, because the documentation for `/wd` does not say it can disable errors or diagnostics in general, just warnings -- so I am not sure if that is supposed to be supported... A wild guess: somehow the parser still allows it but triggers an error; and `/Tc` simply disables this error (among other things) -- which in turn makes it possible to disable the error, even if it is not supposed to be possible.

Comment: @Acorn It's documented on [Compiler Warning C4430](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173696.aspx) that `/wd` can be used to turn it off, so yes, it's supposed to be supported.

Comment: @hvd: Indeed, it seems so -- thanks for that bit of knowledge! It even works on `/permissive-`, which I'd argue it shouldn't...

Answer (score 0):

Reformatting a bit:

```
const CHAR_BIT = 8;
```

Invalid code in C++, it looks like old C code. Let's assume that `const int` was meant.

```
#define BITS(type)       (CHAR_BIT * (int)sizeof(type))
```

Returns the number of bits that a type takes assuming 8-bit bytes, because `sizeof` returns the number of bytes of the object representation of `type`.

```
#define HIBIT(type)      ((type) (1 << (BITS(type) - 1)))
```

Assuming `type` is a signed integer in two's complement, this would return an integer of that type with the highest bit set. For instance, for a 8-bit integer, you would get `1 << (8 - 1) == 1 << 7 == 0b10000000 == -1`.

```
#define TYPE_MAX(type)   ((type) ~HIBIT(type));
```

The bitwise `not` of the previous thing, i.e. flips each bit. Following the same example as before, you would get `~0b10000000 == 0b01111111 == 127`.

```
const SHRT_MAX = TYPE_MAX(short);
```

Again invalid, both in C and C++. In C++ due to the missing `int`, in C due to the fact that `CHAR_BIT` is not a constant expression. Let's assume `const int`. Uses the previous code to get the maximum of the `short` type.