# Unsigned const var? unsigned const what?

Tags: c

I'm digging through some code, and a function that I found takes (as one of the arguments)

```
unsigned const cookie
```

What does that mean? Does the compiler default that to an unsigned integer, or is unsigned itself a datatype (That doesn't make sense to me)?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171839/what-is-the-unsigned-datatype. `unsigned` is same as `unsigned int`.

Comment: What's with the downvoting? This isn't something that's easy to understand and results don't come up anywhere for "unsigned const". Sure I may have missed "unsigned datatype" but that phrase doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default type for qualifiers such as those in C is `int`. Therefore,

```
unsigned const
```

will be interpreted by the compiler as

```
unsigned const int
```

---

If you're interested, you can find some on this behaviour in those posts:

- [What is the default type for C const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171602/what-is-the-default-type-for-c-const)
- [what is the unsigned datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171839/what-is-the-unsigned-datatype)

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned` is a keyword to specify that a numeric data type won't have values below zero.

If you create a `unsigned` identifier without specifying the data type, `int` will be assumed.