# Which section in C89 standard allows the "implicit int" rule?

Tags: c, standards, language-lawyer, c89, implicit-int

While using `gcc`, the code:

```
register a = 3;
static b = 3;
```

it is allowed while using the `-std=c89 -pedantic-errors` flags, although there is a warning.

However it receive an error with the `-std=c99 -pedantic-errors` flags.

I wonder which section of the C89 standards allows the "implicit int" rule?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The section that allowed the *implicit int* rule in C89 would be section `3.5.2` *Type specifiers* which says (*emphasis mine*):

> int , signed , signed int , **or no type specifiers**

Keith Thompson in the comments points out that in C90 the section is `6.5.2` and says, *The only difference is some introductory material required by ISO, resulting in a renumbering of the sections*.

In [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) where this changed, the section is `6.7.2` *Type specifiers* and it says:

> int, signed, or signed int

This is also covered in document [N661: Disallow implicit "int" in declarations](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/text/n661.txt) which says:

> Change in 6.5.2 Type specifiers; add new sentence at
>           beginning of first paragraph of Constraints:
>                   At least one type specifier shall be given in
>                   the declaration specifiers in a declaration.
>
> ```
>     Change in 6.5.2 Type specifiers, Constraints, from:
>             -- int, signed, signed int, or no type
>                specifiers
>     to:
>             -- int, signed, or signed int
> ```

Comment: Section 3.5.2 in the 1989 ANSI C standard is section 6.5.2 in the 1990 ISO C standard. (The two standards describe exactly the same language. The only difference is some introductory material required by ISO, resulting in a renumbering of the sections.)